# Exception in django: Query set have no attribute user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here i am simply using User model from `django.contrib.auth.models import User` and I have a custom userprofile model where user foreign key in that django built in User model , well i have created an email_address field which can manually update by a user, and there is an other email field which is built in inside django User model , I want to update that email field as userprofile email_address field update.
I am simply getting user object which username and try to get email of that user object but getting an error : **'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'email'**

models.py

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(username=self.user.username)
        print(user_obj,'user object')
        print(user_obj.email,'email have a user') 
        email = self.email_address
        user_obj.email = self.email_address
        print(user_obj.email,'email have a user') 
        user_obj.save(user_obj.email)
        super(UserProfile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_obj` is not a `User` object, it is a `QuerySet` of `User` objects.

You can retrieve a single `User` object with [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username=self.user.username)
    user_obj.email = self.email_address
    user_obj.save()
    super(UserProfile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But here you can actually simply use the `self.user` object:

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    user = self.user
    user.email = self.email_address
    user.save()
    super(UserProfile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That being said, I would advise *not* to store data twice. So in case the `User` object has an `email` address, there is no need to store this in the `UserProfile` model as well. You can easily access this with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    @property
    def email_address(self):
        return self.user.email
```

This thus means that you access the `email` address of the related `User` object. This avoids data duplication, which will make it hard to keep data in sync. Especially since the `.save()` method will not run for example for bulk create/updates by the Django ORM.